# when i submit the contact form i want to clear from fields?

Tags: jquery, contact-form

I submit contact form well. everything is working fine but when i submit the from i want clear all field details. the input are not refreshing.

my javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonme').click(function(){
        $.post("send.php", $("#myform").serialize(),  function(response) {   
            $('#contactstatus').html(response);
                //$('#success').hide('slow');
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can i refresh input for that what i have to add in myscript

Comment: `document.getElementById('myform').reset();`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('#myform').each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#myForm").trigger('reset');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yj4S5/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
$('input')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

## **HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="reset" id="reset" />
    <input type="button" id="buttonme" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:reset").hide();
    $('#buttonme').click(function () {
        $("input:reset").click();
    });
});
```

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8URw4/

In your case 
add HTML in your forn

```
<input type="reset" id="reset" />
```

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonme').click(function(){
        $.post("send.php", $("#myform").serialize(),  function(response) {   
            $('#contactstatus').html(response);
                //$('#success').hide('slow');
            $("input:reset").click();//add this to your code
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

or you can simply use

## **js**

```
 $('form').trigger('reset');
```

Comment: thanks brooo. even why dey down voted me. i donno. but i got solution. thnkas to all

Comment: don't know why they down voted you :/ if you have go the solution make it as answer so that other people with same problem can find the solution.